Find the value of the interior angles of a polygon
I have coordinates of points $(x, y)$. By connecting these points we get a polygon in which I have to get values of its internal angles.
For example points = $[3,1], [3,3], [1,3], [3,5], [7,5], [7,1]$

So, to get the values of all the interior angles of a polygon as list: $[90, 270, 45, 135, 90, 90]$
I only have coordinates!!! Please tell me how to find out the values of the angles between the lines.
In the picture I have given a rather simple example. In reality my polygons will not be so straight, but for example



As mentioned in my comment on StackOverflow, you can find an interior angle between three points by converting those points into vectors, and use the following known formula (for the scalar product):
$$ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = || a ||\cdot || b ||\cdot \cos(\text{angle}(\vec{a},\vec{b}))$$
As correctly mentioned in the first comments, this does not determine the angle exactly, like in the following example:

$\angle{B} = 90° \text{ and } \angle{C} = 270°$, or:
$\angle{B} = 270° \text{ and } \angle{C} = 90°$



You still need a way to determine whether or not the angle is greater than 180 degrees

You take inverse cosine so the angle automatically goes $\le180$ degrees.
